# Content type allowing multiple nodes to be selected / linked

Tags: views

I have a content type of 'tutors' which currently has basic fields for their biography.

I have another content type 'venues' which lists the training venues my client operates.

I wish to allow the site admins to flag which tutors teach at which venues - allowing then a list of tutors to be shown on the venue page.

I am comfortable creating a view for each venue page - but what is my best mechanism to allow for a list of all available venues to be listed in the admin with a checkbox or similar so that a tutor can be 'assigned' to one or multiple venues?

Trying to achieve this in D7.

Comment: Try this out with entity reference field which can list out how many tutors are linked to a particular venue node

Comment: Thanks @AshishDeynap - do you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: Any clues how to use the entity reference values as filters for a view on the page?